# How to write grammar for the below criterion - Grammar for ANTLR4 - Custom Expressions

Tags: javascript, antlr, antlr4, grammar

I have a simple expression that I am writing and I am looking for a way to write grammar for such expressions so that ANTLR can generate the lexer and parser using this file.

My expressions don't have any assignments. They are just a bunch of operations on some pre existing fields. **They don't need to be evaluated.**

I have a bunch of pre defined functions ( such as SUM, MEAN, SUBSTR which the backend understands ) and these functions are applied on some existing fields.

The operators I need are :- + , - , * , /
Brackets : ( , ) for opening and closing.
Functions ( keywords ) : SUM, MEAN, MAX SUBSTR.

Examples :-

1. **( A + B )** , this can also be **SUM**(A,B)
2. (MEAN(A, B, C) + MAX( X, MIN(Y,Z)) + 2)/4
3. SUBSTR("TEST1",0,6)

The expression can extend to multi line.

Here is the basic version that I've written.

```
grammar ExpressionGrammar;

parse: (expr)+ EOF
    ;

expr: expr '/' expr
    | expr '*' expr  
    | expr '+' expr
    | expr '-' expr
    | NUM
    | function
    ;

function : ID '(' arguments? ')';

arguments: expr ( ',' expr)*;

/* Tokens */ 

OPEN_PAR : '(' ;
CLOSE_PAR : ')' ;

NUM : '0' | '-'?[1-9][0-9]*;
ID : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z]*;
COMMENT: '//' ~[\r\n]* -> skip;
WS: [ \t\n]+ -> skip;
```

Eventually I would also have to run some validations on the expression typed by the user. If I input a string inside a MAX() function which only accepts numbers, I should be able to know the line/position where the error is at and notify the user. I believe this comes during the parsing phase ? But just putting it out there, in case there are any inputs and if this grammar can help me identify that.

Comment: I'd start by reading the ANTLR documentation, and/or doing some ANTLR tutorials. When you've done that, and are stuck in the process of actually writing the grammar, feel free to ask a question on SO. Questions like yours where there's no actual technical question, but rather a "can someone guide me?", are not well suited here (see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ). I you did already start writing the grammar, please add it to your question and explain what's wrong with it.

Comment: @BartKiers My bad, I should've added it before posting the question. Could you please take a look at it now ? I also added 3 test snippets. Just wanted to see if this grammar would be any valid and if I am missing any corner cases. I've added the function implementation from one of your answers which proved very helpful. My expression can sometimes start with brackets ( 2nd example ) , hence I added (expr)+ , is that the right way to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of remarks:

- I'd not glue the minus to a number in the lexer, but rather match n unary eexpression
- you're missing the nested expression in your `expr` rule `'(' expr ')'`
- you probably also want to match an `ID` inside the `expr` rule
- `*` and `/` usually have the same precedence, so should be grouped inside the same alternative (same for `+` and `-`)

Something like this would make more sense:

```
parse: (expr)+ EOF
     ;

expr: MIN expr
    | expr ( MUL | DIV ) expr
    | expr ( ADD | MIN ) expr
    | NUM
    | ID
    | function
    | '(' expr ')'
    ;

function : ID '(' arguments? ')';

arguments: expr ( ',' expr)*;

/* Tokens */

MUL : '*';
DIV : '/';
MIN : '-';
ADD : '+';
OPEN_PAR : '(' ;
CLOSE_PAR : ')' ;

NUM : '0' | [1-9][0-9]*;
ID : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z]*;
COMMENT: '//' ~[\r\n]* -> skip;
WS: [ \t\n]+ -> skip;
```

> Eventually I would also have to run some validations on the expression typed by the user. If I input a string inside a MAX() function which only accepts numbers, I should be able to know the line/position where the error is at and notify the user. I believe this comes during the parsing phase ? But just putting it out there, in case there are any inputs and if this grammar can help me identify that.

Such semantic checks should be done after parsing. The parser creates a parse tree. Inside a visitor you then walk this parse tree and evaluate the input. Then you can produce errors/warnings if the evaluated input does not have the proper type for certain functions.

Comment: Thanks Bart, makes sense now. Just a quick question - "expr : MIN expr" In this line, what does MIN signify ?

Comment: Also, if I have to check for matching parenthesis after parsing , do I have to write the function grammar as " function: ID OPEN_PAR arguments? CLOSE_PAR ; " Is this necessary for tokenization ? or just adding a token as OPEN_PART and CLOSE_PAR as I did in the above grammar sufficient ?

Comment: `MIN` stands for minus. It's the rule that matches `-`: `MIN : '-';`

Comment: *"... as I did in the above grammar sufficient ?"* yes, that will do fine.

Comment: I have an expression like this :-  
 (Fields.V1)*(Fields.V2) + (Constants.Value1)*(Constants.Value2) .  The ANTLR parser generated the following text from the grammar above **(FieldsV1)*(FieldsV2)+(Constants<missing ')'>** . As you can see, the "dots" in Fields.V1 and Fields.V2 are missing from the text and also there is a  *<missing ')'* Error node.

Comment: Could you please let me know what's going wrong here ? Why are the dots missing and why is that Constants.Value1 not being parsed correctly.

Comment: Please create a new question for that @Veryon890. Be sure to include your current grammar in that question.

Comment: thanks , posted it here [New Question ANLTR4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66005429/antlr4-grammar-issue-with-dot-in-fields-and-extended-expressions)