# ANTLR4 Grammar - Issue with "dot" in fields and extended expressions

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have the following ANTLR4 Grammar

```
grammar ExpressionGrammar;

parse: (expr)
     ;

expr: MIN expr
    | expr ( MUL | DIV ) expr
    | expr ( ADD | MIN ) expr
    | NUM
    | function
    | '(' expr ')'
    ;

function : ID '(' arguments? ')';

arguments: expr ( ',' expr)*;

/* Tokens */

MUL : '*';
DIV : '/';
MIN : '-';
ADD : '+';
OPEN_PAR : '(' ;
CLOSE_PAR : ')' ;

NUM : '0' | [1-9][0-9]*;
ID : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z]*;
COMMENT: '//' ~[\r\n]* -> skip;
WS: [ \t\n]+ -> skip;
```

I have an input expression like this :-

```
(Fields.V1)*(Fields.V2) + (Constants.Value1)*(Constants.Value2)
```

The ANTLR parser generated the following text from the grammar above :-

```
(FieldsV1)*(FieldsV2)+(Constants<missing ')'>
```

As you can see, the "dots" in Fields.V1 and Fields.V2 are missing from the text and also there is a <missing ')' Error node. I believe I should somehow make ANTLR understand that an expression can also have fields with dot operators.

A question on top of this :-

```
 (Var1)(Var2)
```

ANTLR is not throwing me error for this above scenario , the expressions should not be (Var1)(Var2) -- It should always have the operator (var1)*(var2) or (var1)+(var2) etc. The parser error tree is not generating this error. How should the grammar be modified to make sure even this scenario is taken into consideration.

Comment: Start by adding `EOF` to your `parse` rule (and remove the unnecessary parentheses).

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect to happen: I don't see any rule in your lexer that matches a `.`...

Comment: @BartKiers That's right. I want to know where exactly should I add that matching. Because my parser shouldn't actually split the "dot" . It should be as a whole "Fields.V1"

Comment: @MikeLischke EOF - Are you referring to the first parse: (expr) ? You want me to change it to **expr EOF**  ?

Comment: *"It should be as a whole "Fields.V1""* then you should edit your `ID` rule to make it also include the `.`. But I'm confused: is this your own grammar, or did you find it somewhere? I get the impression you're blindly trying thing without really understanding ANTLR. Perhaps take a step back and start with a basic ANTLR tutorial?

Comment: @Veryon890 yes, exactly, when added any additional input not matched by your grammar will cause a parse error then.

Comment: @BartKiers I've been trying to learn from examples and fit things for my needs as I thought my grammar is pretty simple and standard, looks like I am missing out on some major points . I would have to take a step back for sure and read more about this. Thanks! Just a quick question - when ANTLR generated the parser tree (AST ) for me 1+2 is being stored as children: ["1","+","2"] . The numbers are being stored as strings , is it again an issue with my Grammar ?

Comment: No, everything ANTLR matches are strings: it is up to you to convert the string `"123"` into the numerical value `123` when walking your parse tree after parsing is done.

Comment: @Bart Kiers ohk, was this deliberately done by Antlr ? For my simple example MAX(1,2) - I have to run a validation to check whether the arguments are numbers or strings . If it's Max(1,"124" ) I should show a validation failure, but when walking down the children of ArgumentsContext of the Parse tree the "text" field is being generated as strings and there is no way for me to validate it ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: if the string matched your NUM Lexer rule, then you'll be safe in converting it to an Int (or whatever native number type you plan to use (looks like Ints but the Lexer Rule)).  ANTLRs job is just to sort things out for you so you know how to interpret the input.  From that point on you need to handle tasks like converting NUM token strings to your native number format.

Comment: Yes, ANTLR is no different in that aspect than all other parser generators. How should ANTLR know that the text in your input source `"123"` is an `int` in your target language? And what about the text `"99999999999999999999999999999"`, should that also be converted by ANTLR as an `int`? All ANTLR does is match characters, and a character `'1'` is just a character like `'A'`. I encourage you to take that step back now, and do some reading first: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/index.md and https://tomassetti.me/antlr-mega-tutorial

Comment: I'll second Bart's comment to go read the tutorials.  It's pretty common for programmers to try to do ANTLR by looking at a few examples and hacking at it until something works.  (It's also pretty easy to spot (so that's probably why Mike and Bart are prompting with comments rather than serving up a full answer)).  You really need to understand the principals.  (I'd add that, if you have intentions of really doing much with ANTLR, then "The Definitive ANTLR4 Reference" from prog programmers is w worthwhile investment/read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To recognize `ID`s like `Fields.V1`, change you Lexer rule for `ID` to something like this:

```
fragment ID_NODE: [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9]*;
ID: ID_NODE ('.' ID_NODE)*;
```

Notice, since each "node" of the ID follows the same rule, I made it a lexer fragment that I could use to compose the ID rule.  I also added `0-9` to the second part of the fragment, since it appears that you want to allow numbers in `ID`s

Then the `ID` rule uses the fragment to build out the Lexer rule that allows for dots in the `ID`.

You also didn't add `ID` as a valid `expr` alternative

To handle detection of the error condition in `(Var1)(Var2)`, you need Mike's advice to add the EOF Lexer rule to the end of the `parse` parser rule.  Without the `EOF`, ANTLR will stop parsing as soon as it reaches the end of a recognized expr (`(Var1)`).  The `EOF` says "and then you need to find an `EOF`", so ANTLR will continue parsing into the `(Var2)` and give you the error.

A revised version that handles both of your examples:

```
grammar ExpressionGrammar;

parse: expr EOF;

expr:
    MIN expr
    | expr ( MUL | DIV) expr
    | expr ( ADD | MIN) expr
    | NUM
    | ID
    | function
    | '(' expr ')';

function: ID '(' arguments? ')';

arguments: expr ( ',' expr)*;

/* Tokens */

MUL: '*';
DIV: '/';
MIN: '-';
ADD: '+';
OPEN_PAR: '(';
CLOSE_PAR: ')';

NUM: '0' | [1-9][0-9]*;
fragment ID_NODE: [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9]*;
ID: ID_NODE ('.' ID_NODE)*;
COMMENT: '//' ~[\r\n]* -> skip;
WS: [ \t\n]+ -> skip;
```

(Now that I've read through the comments, this is pretty much just applying the suggestions in the comments)